# Redirect Domain Name to Particular Page(html) in Opencart?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, opencart, http-redirect

I have a website build on opencart platform. currently this website on local server. I want to redirect my main domain to a HTML Page. How do i achieve this? and is opencart allows to redirect domain to HTML page?

Comment: do you want the home page to be some page other than the index page?

Comment: Yes. Basically i have intro page in HTML. when website loads it should redirect me to that HTML page. I will give enter website link which will take user to Main website. Website will have home page link which will have index.php link. for eg. http://www.panad.in/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not opencart issue, you should add this line to your `htaccess` file :

```
DirectoryIndex your.html index.php
```